# How to use function pointer in C?

Tags: c, gcc, pthreads

I am writing pthread program which contain functions as given below and I want to call another function in between one function.

```
void *fun1(void *arg1)
{
fun2(NULL);
}
void *fun2(void *arg)
{
fun1(NULL);
}
```

When I am calling another function as shown above I am getting error as shown below

error: conflicting types for ‘fun2’

note: previous implicit declaration of ‘fun2’ was here

How can I call fun2 in between fun1

Comment: Why put C in the question title and then tag it C++? Removed it for you

Comment: Especially since this is a different error in C++ than in C…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare :

`void *fun2(void *);`

before `fun1`

The compiler assumes the default return type as `int` so you need to tell it the actual prototype before use

Comment: Also, he needs to return a pointer from a function that's supposed to return a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

During compilation you have not given a prototype for `fun2` like:

```
void * fun2(void *);
```

Since there is no forward declaration hence the compiler implicitly assumes it will return an `int`. (I mean this is how my compiler behaves) So it will have conflicting types.

The best practice is:

```
void * fun1(void *);
void * fun2(void *);

void * fun1(void *arg1)
{
    fun2(NULL);
    //return missing
}
void * fun2(void *arg)
{
    fun1(NULL);
    //return missing
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/* forward declaration */
void *fun2(void *arg);

void *fun1(void *arg1)
{
  fun2(NULL);
}
void *fun2(void *arg)
{
  fun1(NULL);
}
```

Note that, as written, you have an infinite recursion. These two functions will just call each other until the program runs out of stack and crashes.

Answer (score 2):

You must declare your function before calling it.Keep habit of declaring functions in header file or top of your `.c` file . You should

```
void *fun2(void *args);
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets go wild and assume that you have you have used forward declarations.

`fun1` (there is a misnomer) calls `fun2` then that calls `fun1` that calls `fun2` ad infinitum - until the blessed machine runs of of stack (patience?) and gives up.